# tkinter : Spinbox, validatecommand and invalidcommand

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input

I'm trying to use a Spinbox widget in a script and I would like the Spinbox not to accept incorrect input. I would like the input to be an integer between 0 and 50. I found that I could use the option `validatecommand` to call a registered function to check the input, and the option `invalidcommand` to do stuff if the function called by `validatecommand` returns `False`. So what I want is:

- Check if input is correct
- if it's not, change the value in the Spinbox to be a default value (say 0)

Here's my code for setting the Spinbox:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

validate_input = (root.register(correct_input), '%P')
invalid_input = (root.register(incorrect_input), '%W')

x_select = tk.Spinbox(root, from_ = 0, to = 50,
                      validate = 'all', validatecommand = validate_input,
                      invalidcommand = invalid_input)
x_select.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
```

And here are the functions used to control the input and to change it back to a default value if necessary:

```
def correct_input(text):
    valid = False
    if text.isdigit():
        if (int(text) <= 50 and int(text) >= 0):
            valid = True
    elif text == '':
        valid = True
    return valid

def incorrect_input(widget_name):
    widget = root.nametowidget(widget_name)
    widget.delete(0, 'end')
    widget.insert(0, 0)
```

Problem is, it only works once: if I type 'a' for instance the value in `x_select` will be set to `0` but then input is not checked anymore i.e. I can type whatever I want the input will not be corrected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your question is not really clear

Comment: @ADWAN what is unclear? I ultimately want the user not to be able to type undesired values that I described (any value that is not a number, and any number that's not between 0 and 50). In order to do so, I use the `Spinbox` option `validatecommand` that will call a function when triggered (the trigger is set by the `validate` option). That function is `correct_input`, it returns `True` if input is ok and `False` otherwise. If function called by `validatecommand` returns `False`, then `invalidcommand` calls a function meant to avoid having incorrect input (that function is `incorrect_input`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking [some documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) I found out using the `invalidcommand` was unnecessary since

> a callback function checks the text in the Entry and returns True if the text is valid, or False if not. If the callback returns False, the user's attempt to edit the text will be refused, and the text will be unchanged.

Here my callback function is `correct_input`: if it returns `False`, text will not be changed. So instead of having:

```
x_select = tk.Spinbox(root, from_ = 0, to = 50,
                      validate = 'all', validatecommand = validate_input,
                      invalidcommand = invalid_input)
```

I just write:

```
x_select = tk.Spinbox(root, from_ = 0, to = 50,
                      validate = 'all', validatecommand = validate_input)
```

And I deleted any line related to `incorrect_input`.